# Creating a node type module in Drupal 7.x

Tags: 7, nodes

I am having some deep trouble getting around creating a node type with Drupal 7.x.
My aim is to create a node type that has some form elements within a table grid. Using any of the existing modules is coming across as a challenge because I can't find anything specific to my needs, hence I decided to explore module building and then enabling it as a node.

The tutorial I have is :
http://drupal.org/node/231019 (Create new content type for Drupal 6.x) .. .there isn't any exact tutorial available for Drupal 7.x

I have followed every step but am unable to see the content type appear in my node module.

Anybody has pointers to any resources for this?

Thanks

Comment: Just something to check: Did you enable your module?

Answer (score 2):

Download and look at those wonderful [examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples)